# React Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

After I create a new game via a form I can redirect to newly created game's show page but then if I want to go to the games index page it reloads the newly created game's show page again. I need to refresh to go to the game's index page.

So I created `clearSubmit()` method, changed `hasSubmitted` value to false again, passed the method into the show page's route and in show page's `component(GameShow.js)` I called clearSubmit() method as props.

Right now when I submit the form to create a game I got this error:

```
React Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'state' of 
undefined

src/components/GameShow.js:14

11 | constructor(props) {
12 |   super(props)
13 |   this.state = {
> 14 |     game: this.props.location.state.selectedGame
15 |   }
16 | }
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      games: [],
      name: '',
      img_url: '',
      genre: '',
      platforms: '',
      video_url: '',
      description: '',
      hasSubmitted: false,
      newGame: {}
    }
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.clearSubmit = this.clearSubmit.bind(this)
  }


  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    })
  }


  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { name, img_url, genre, platforms, video_url, description } =
      this.state;

    axios.post('http://localhost:4000/api/games', {
      name: name, img_url:
        img_url, genre: genre, platforms: platforms, video_url: video_url,
      description: description
    })
      .then((result) => {
        this.setState({
          hasSubmitted: true,
          newGame: result.data
        })
      });
  }

  clearSubmit() {
    this.setState({
      hasSubmitted: false
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <main>
            <Route exact path='/games' render={() => {
              let newGame = this.state.newGame
              return this.state.hasSubmitted
                ? <Redirect to=
                  {{
                    pathname: `/games/${this.state.newGame.name}`,
                    state: { selectedGame: newGame }
                  }}
                />
                : <GameForm handleChange={this.handleChange}
                  handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} games={this.state.games}
                />
            }}
            />

            <Route exact path='/games' render={() => {
              return (
                <GameIndex handleChange={this.handleChange}
                  handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} games={this.state.games}
                />
              )
            }}
            />
            <Route path="/games/:name" render={() => {
              return (
                <GameShow clearSubmit={this.clearSubmit} />
              )
            }}
            />
          </main>
        </div>
```

**GameIndex.js**

```
class GameIndex extends Component {
  render() {
    let videoGames = this.props.games.map((game, i) => {
      let pathname = `/games/${game.name}`

      return (
        <div key={i}>
          <p><Link to=
            {{ pathname, state: { selectedGame: game } }}> {game.name}</Link></p>
        </div>
      )
    })
```

**GameShow.js**

```
class GameShow extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.clearSubmit()
  }

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      game: this.props.location.state.selectedGame
    }
  }
```

I couldn't figure out what am I missing.

Thanks.

Comment: You are not passing a `location` prop: `<GameShow clearSubmit={this.clearSubmit} />` .

Comment: I think location prop is a built-in method so how can I pass it into GameShow component?

Comment: from where you want to get location ?

Comment: from inside this route: 

    <Route path="/games/:name" render={() => {
            return (
              <GameShow clearSubmit={this.clearSubmit} />
            )      
          } }
     />

Comment: If you're using render you need to spread the props you receive in the render method to your component: `render={props => <Component {...props} otherProp={false} />}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not pass any props object called location into GameShow.js (When you render the object in App.js).

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to acess

```
this.props.location.state.selectedGame
```

in GameShow but location is not passd as a props to this component,

so your state is coming undefined

Answer (score 0):

```
return this.state.hasSubmitted
  ? 
  <Redirect to=
    {{
      pathname: `/games/${this.state.newGame.name}`,
      state: { selectedGame: newGame }
    }}
  />
  : 
  <GameForm handleChange={this.handleChange}
    handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} games={this.state.games}
  />
```

In the `false` case, you are not passing `state: {selectedGame: newGame}`,
So,your `props` is `undefined` and you get this error.

you can pass blank object `state: {selectedGame: {} }`
here like

```
<GameForm handleChange={this.handleChange}
  handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} games={this.state.games} , state: {selectedGame: {} }
/>
```

and in the constructor,do code sanitization.

```
this.state = {
  game: this.props.state && this.props.state.selectedGame
}
```

Comment: I removed location and right now I got  "Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'selectedGame' of undefined" error.